# no output when requesting date/time from php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Ive created a php file with the current date and time. i also have a html/javascript file which tries to request the output of the php and add it to the html. Im currently getting no response text back and im not sure why.

Bare in mind im a noob at ajax and this is a simple exercise to get learn ajax

This is the html/javascript:

```
<body>
      <p>Current server time:</p>
      <div id="poll"></div>

      <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "polling.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
      </body>
```

This is my php:

```
    <?php

echo date("D M j H:i:s e Y");

?>
```

Comment: just as a note, if the PHP file is pure PHP you don't need the closing `?>` tag - also when do you call loadDoc?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's much more simple and convenient to just use `new Date()` in JS.

Comment: @LeoNapoleon Like he said, it's an exercise to learn ajax

Comment: You put your ajax call in a laodDoc function and never call it (not sure if it's the problem but try to remove your function or call it in your script tag)

Comment: Thanks it was a problem with my function call, feel dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declared the javascript function, but not made the call that function while page load

```
<body>
<p>Current server time:</p>
<div id="poll"></div>

  <script>
   function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "polling.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
   }
   loadDoc(); // ***here you missed****
  </script>
</body>
```